# Cannot get circle radius correct in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a jsfiddle below where I attempt to create a circle 1600 meters in radius. I don't think that I have the projection right, because this circle is definitely smaller than 1600 meters. Measuring on Google Maps I think it's around 1000 meters instead. What do I need to do to correct this please>

Thank you.

```js
var centerLongitudeLatitude = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.733014, 51.982989]);
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: [new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle(centerLongitudeLatitude, 1600))]
  }),
  style: [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 3
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
      })
    })
  ]
});


var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    layer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.733014, 51.982989]),
    zoom: 14
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an inconsistency between the SRS of the vector layer (`EPSG:4326`), and the center and of the circle (`EPSG:3857`). You need to one of the above, not both.

Try to create the layer without specifying `projection`, it would use the default view projection, in this case `EPSG:3857` (because of OSM).

UPDATE:

After building the snippet below, I realize that the proposed change does not affect the result, not sure why just now, so I proposed the use of `Polygon.circular` as an alternative.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>Circle features</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // features
    var radius = 1600;
    var center = [-1.733014, 51.982989]
    var fcircle = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Circle(
        ol.proj.fromLonLat(center),
        radius
      )
    });
    fcircle.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 2
      })
    }));
    var fcircular = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.circular(center, radius, 64).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
    });
    fcircular.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'red',
        width: 1
      })
    }));
    // map
    var view = new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(center),
      zoom: 14
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [fcircle, fcircular]
          })
        })
   ],
   view
  });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks cabesuoun. Unfortunately I'm at the stage of hacking openlayers and know rather little js. Is there any chance you might have enough time to post a snippet to show the solution? If so many thanks, and if not fully understood.

Comment: I have updated the answer .. I am pretty sure of seeing something about this in SO but I couldn't find it now .. As an alternative you can use `Polygon.circular` .. I will try to look again this, or maybe someone else explain reason behind

Comment: Thank you, I have hacked a temporary workaround for now - at my lattitude across the United Kingdom I can just apply a constant multiplication factor of 1.62 to the radius to be close enough for my purposes. Clearly I'd like to do this the right way though! I'm a bit hesitant to use a polygon, because I know that some of my clients will notice the lack of a smooth curve and will dislike that (as indeed do I). That's something I need to avoid. Thanks!

Comment: Although in fairness, your polygon is actually pretty good looking, and when I increase the number of segments to 256 it's indistinguishable from a circle. So at this point if it's possible to get rid of the polygon that would be a nice clean solution, otherwise this works well. Many many thanks.

Comment: ol.geom.Polygon.circular is only needed for large radius circles which wouldn't look circular in the projection.  For small radius circle simple divide the radius by the point resolution at the circle center `ol.proj.getPointResolution(viewProjection, 1, center)`

Comment: Hi Mike, can you please explain where I can get `viewProjection` from? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mike and cabesuon I have a solution, posted here for future readers.

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.733014, 51.982989]),
    zoom: 14
  })
});

var centerLongitudeLatitude = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.733014, 51.982989]);
var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
var pointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(viewProjection , 1, centerLongitudeLatitude );
var radius = 1600 / pointResolution;
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: [new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle(centerLongitudeLatitude, radius))]
  }),
  style: [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 3
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
      })
    })
  ]
});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```